# UNC path with hostname omitted?

Tags: windows, path, file-sharing, unc

I have an application that opens a file, the path of which is set to what looks like a UNC path, but with the double slash and hostname removed i.e. instead of

```
\\HOSTNAME\SHARED\FILE
```

it has

```
\SHARED\FILE
```

This refers to the share `SHARED` on the local machine.

This all worked fine, until I switched the application to run as a Windows service. Now the application cannot open the file.

The service is running as a domain account which has full control of the share.

I would like to understand the meaning of this path format, why a Windows service can't access a file referred to with it but a console application can, and how to make this work without changing the path (if possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an UNC path anymore. It's a regular local path that starts at the root (`\`) of the same drive as the current working directory of the process.

That is, if the cwd is `c:\windows`, the path `\users\anthony` would refer to `c:\users\anthony`.

Comment: OK, Windows services run in `%WinDir%\System32` so `\SHARED\FILE` is referring to `C:\SHARED\FILE` but `SHARED` is actually on the `D:\` drive. Thank you.